# Jquery live keyup not working

Tags: jquery, live

I have text box

```
<input type="text"  name="extraQty0"  class="extraEvent" value="1"/>
```

used following code

```
$(".extraEvent").live('keyup',function(){
   alert('test');
});
```

This is not working But if i use 'click'   instead of 'keyup' the alert will work. What could be wrong?

Comment: what version of jquery are you using?

Comment: It works for me http://jsfiddle.net/ynhat/WYjwN/

Comment: @Jason i'm using jquery v1.3.1

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you are using jQuery version 1.3.1. Support for the `keyup` event for `live()` wasn't introduced until later. Update your jQuery to either the [latest version](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.min.js) or at least 1.4.x and you should be fine.

[Source](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

Comment: Haa you are right Thank you. I have downloaded jquery 1.6 and the keyup event is working now.. But facing another issue when i reload the page firebug is throughing following error "a.getAttribute is not a function"

Comment: Hmmm... I have downloaded 1.5 and everything is working fine now.. Thanks again Jason...

Answer (score 3):

That's strange. Could you try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".extraEvent").live('keyup', function(){
    alert('test');
  });  
});
```

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: thanks for the reply. Yes actually i have already wrapped the codes inside $(document).ready.... :(